# What cools off faster a square or a disc?

Tags: thermodynamics

What cools off faster and why,  a square (4 right angles, all sides same length)with an area of 100 inches or a disc with an area of 100 inches.  The same material and thickness.

Comment: Do you mean a *cube* rather than a square, and a *sphere* rather than a disc?

Comment: Not a cube or sphere, think of a frying pan that is either square or round.

Comment: Inches is not a unit of area.

Comment: Also, do you mean conductive, convective or radiative cooling?

Answer (score 3):

The only difference is more perimeter.  You will have slightly more loss from the corners, so the square will cool faster.

Comment: If the square cools down, just slightly, how would a square vs a disc behave while heating them up?  Would it take 5% more energy to heat up? If it is easier say the material is cast iron with thermal conductivity of 55 and thickness of .25 inches.  Thank you.

Comment: The added cooldown is because there is more area for convection.  When you start, there is not temperature difference with the surroundings, so they will heat at the same rate.  As it gets hot, the heat loss increases more for the square, so it won't heat as fast.  But if it is a thin plate, the difference is very small.

Comment: Fun to note that if you make the perimeters equal, the square still cools down faster because of the lower area of the square.  It will actually cool faster than the equal area case.